# Apostrophe, caret, or quote mark appear depending on cell alignment in MS Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, settings

There is one computer in our department which is having this problem, which causes me to think that a default setting has been changed. I am asking for any advice or recommendations. This setting is screwing up the VBA code I've written, causing it to be useless for that computer.

**Problem**: every single cell's value in the worksheet has a leading character which changes depending on its alignment. Left aligned cells receive an apostrophe (`'`), centered cells receive a caret (`^`), and right aligned cells receive a double quote mark (`"`). Every single web page says to change the format from Text to General, but that doesn't fix it (if the solution is different from selecting Home tab, Number section, dropdown -> select General, then let me know).

This issue is happening with every single worksheet opened on this computer and occurs no matter what type of data is entered, and it needs to stop.

[Left Alignment Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0oNi.png),

[Centered Alignment Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud0WT.png)

(I would add the Right Alignment Photo, but I need more posts before I gain permission)

I'm in need of a solution to stop having these characters appear. I don't know what is causing them therefore I don't know how to deactivate it. But I do know that it is automatic, and nobody is inserting those characters.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

My options as I see it:

- Preferred: Fix the problem,
- Second: Uninstall and re-install MS excel,
- Last resort: change the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://ask.brothersoft.com/what-does-a-caret-symbol-mean-in-microsoft-excel-77529.html

> **Converted Lotus 1-2-3 Worksheet**
>
> You may see a ^ in the Formula Bar if
> you open a Lotus 1-2-3 spreadsheet. Lotus 1-2-3 uses special
> characters to indicate formatting. These characters appear in Excel's
> Formula Bar; however, they do not affect the cell. The characters are
> the apostrophe ('), which means the text is left-aligned, the
> quotation mark (") for right-aligned text, the caret (^) for centered
> text and the backslash () for justified text.

Check the settings under: *Excel Options > Advanced > Lotus Compatibility*

Comment: You are an absolute life savior. That was exactly it. Thank you for a quick response and your infinite wisdom.

Comment: Hey I just looked it up on the Google.  But now I do know i suppose....

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer confused me for a sec, so here's some clarity:

**Examine** the settings under: *Excel Options > Advanced > Lotus Compatibility*

The fix is to *uncheck* the box for Transition navigation keys